# No matching version found for @ngrx/core@^6.1.0

Tags: angular

I am upgrading my angular 4 to angular 6 application.  I have updated my package.json and getting the following error  No matching version found for @ngrx/core@^6.1.0. Not sure what the problem is. I am finding it difficult to figure our which dependency it is missing. Please find the copy of my Package.json below

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "irm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "npm run lint && ng build",
    "build-dev": "npm run lint && ng build --watch",
    "build-aot": "ng build --prod --aot=true",
    "build-pdf": "ng build --app=pdf",
    "test": "ng test --reporters=progress --browsers=ChromeHeadless --sourcemaps=false",
    "testCI": "ng test --watch=false --single-run=true --reporters=junit,progress --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check --format stylish",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "verify": "npm run testCI",
    "ci": "npm install && npm run verify && npm run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.8.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
    "@ngrx/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.0",
    "@wtw/platform": "1.0.32",
    "angular-esri-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "highcharts-histogram-bellcurve": "^0.1.7",
    "moment-range": "4.0.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.7",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.8.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.10.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.4.4",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "npm-check-updates": "^2.14.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "puppeteer": "^1.8.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "cpy-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1"

  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, it is because the @ngrx/core package is no longer used. It never went past version 1.2 in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Ngrx packages as stated in their documentation at https://github.com/ngrx/platform

> @ngrx/store  @ngrx/effects  @ngrx/router-store  @ngrx/store-devtools 
>   @ngrx/entity  @ngrx/schematics

**Link to there migration guide:**
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't needed anymore:

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v4

> @ngrx/core is no longer needed and conflicts with @ngrx/store. Remove
>   the dependency from your project.